# Conectar Angular 10 con una api en contenedores docker

Tags: angular, api, docker

Tengo una aplicación en Angular 10 y utilizo una api para conectarme a un servicio. Ambos estan hospedados en un contenedor docker corriendo en Ubuntu-Linux.

La aplicación está publicada, pero, por razones de seguridad, no deseo publicar la api.

Ambos estan exponiendo los puertos correctos y están en la misma red interna respondiendo a una llamada localhost (cada uno con un alias : app apunta a localhost:xxx, api apunta a localhost:yyy que es donde responden los contenedores.).

Llamando a la aplicación y al swagger de la api, todo funciona correctamente tanto en local como en el servidor porque ambas máquinas tienen la misma configuración y tienen instalada la api y la aplicación.

La cuestion es que, al ejecutarse Angular en la maquina cliente, no tiene acceso a la api que está en el servidor salvo que la exponga públicamente.

¿ Conoceis algún método por el cual pueda conectar ambos contenedores sin tener que publicar la api ?.

Gracias de antemano y felices fiestas.

Comment: Por definición no puedes no publicar la API (Interfaz **Pública** de Aplicación) si quieres que sea consumida desde un navegador de un usuario. Si no es este el escenario, por favor, intenta [edit] tu pregunta y aclararlo.

Comment: Gracias Pablo, buscaba un atajo :). Dado que ambos comparten espacio y red en docker queria saber si alguien ha podido hacer un puente. La solución que se tengo en mente (para evitar publicar la api porque es un poco delicada) es publicar un endpoint que haga de puente y oculte la informacion de la api al exterior. Intentaba ahorrarme ese paso :). Gracias por contestar y Felices Fiestas!.